# We cant' think in nothing!

Tags: logic

If you ask someone to describe someone else, or just tell him who is that person? what is the natural answer? of course he will respond which person?, because he never saw him before. And it's clear that we can't think in vacuum (thinking about nothing) because thinking is a prove of our existence. So now the trivial question is how could some talk about something that he have never saw before?, like for example god, hell and heaven ...ect.

Comment: You need to put some serious effort into making this question more readable. I can't even understand it enough to offer constructive improvement advice. Please take some time to rephrase this and use proper punctuation. Closing pending revisions...

Answer (score 3):

You really need to clean up your question:

- First, the situation in which someone asks someone else about a third person is underdescribed: that (the 2nd?) doesn't know (the 3rd?) comes as a surprise.
- Then you introduce this idea that we cannot think about nothing (maybe you mean that we cannot *not think*?), and connect it somehow with, I take it, Descartes' cogito. But the fact that thinking is a proof of existence doesn't entail that not thinking (let alone thinking about nothing) is a proof of nonexistence.
- Finally, we have the "trivial question" whether we can talk of something we have never seen before. It is unclear how this third question is related to anything of the above.

In any event, that we can think and talk about stuff we are not (in Russell's turn of phrase) acquainted with is unproblematic: we become competent users of a singular term that refers, say, to Socrates (whom neither I nor anyone I know have ever met) by becoming a link in a chain of speakers that takes us all the way back to people that *was* acquainted with Socrates. We are, as Gareth Evans puts it in "The Varieties of Reference", introduced to a name-using practice. You may want to check Mark Sainsbury's "Reference Without Referents" for a more contemporary discussion of these ideas. In Sainsbury's version of the theory, a name-using practice can exist even in the absence of a referent -- think of the unsuccessful name 'Vulcano', that tried to refer to a (nonexistent) planet between Mercury and the Sun. This would be an example of speech (and thought) without an entity we are thinking or talking about.

Believers in God, hell, and the like, I take it, believe that we have been introduced to name-using practices of terms that refer to those entities: think Moses, or Christ, who were, the story goes, acquainted with some of those things.

An interesting case is our apparent ability to refer to abstracta ("the number 2" successfully refer to the number 2, it seems). Here, of course, acquaintance or causal contact of any kind is impossible. One idea that I find attractive is that we don't really refer to such entities. We merely *make believe* that we do; we *fictionalize* about them. For the best worked out theory along these lines, read Kendall Walton's "Mimesis as Make-Believe", or the latest papers by Stephen Yablo on the philosophy of mathematics.

Comment: Good answer. However, I would add that in some cases, it is not possible to be acquainted with something even indirectly, yet we can imagine it: these cases are abstract concepts and ideas such as a simple square or circle.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will say something about that.